# Android shared library built on linux host doesn't link properly with library build on Windows host

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arm, armv7

I am compiling a set of several C++ libraries to arm-v7a using the Android NDK on Windows. I am compiling using ndk-build, for the most part. However, one of the libraries I am using (let's call it libproblem.so) has a rather complex makefile, so I use the ajb-tools (https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ajb-tools/trunk/android/android-cross/android-cross) to call the makefile to build just that library on **Linux**. Both of these use the same NDK version.

I've made a few changes to the defaults in the android-cross script, to match my Application.mk, including:

```
export ANDROID_GCCVER=${ANDROID_GCCVER-4.8}
export ANDROID_PLAT_API_VER=${ANDROID_PLAT_API_VER-10} #not sure what this does...
export ANDROID_PLAT_NDK_VER=${ANDROID_PLAT_NDK_VER-9} #gingerbread
export ANDROID_TUNE=${ANDROID_TUNE-"-mandroid $ANDROID_TUNE_THUMB -mthumb-interwork -Wno-psabi -fpic -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -march=armv7-a -finline-limit=64"}
```

This seems to work fine, and gives me a library whose output to `file` gives me this:

```
../obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libproblem.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, 
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

I am then linking it with the other libraries using the following in my Makefile.mk.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := problem
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(JNI_PATH)/../libs/prebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libproblem.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

However, this causes a linking error. The library that depends on libproblem fails to create a shared object, stating:

```
d:/Code/project/jni/SomeCode.cpp:191: error: undefined reference to 'Problem::Client::Client(std::shared_ptr<Problem::Data> const&)'
```

The function of course exists. If I run `nm` on the libproblem.so in MinGW, I see the function there (albeit mangled).

My only line of thought currently is that there is an issue using two different Host OSes. Because what is particularly strange, is that ndk-build links libproblem.so with the rest of my objects succesfully if I use linux as the host OS for running ndk-build. (Keep in mind both Linux and Windows have the same NDK version, NDKr10b, 32-bit target for 64-bit host).

Or have I missed something in the android-cross script that is building that library in a way that's incompatible with my version of ndk-build?

**UPDATE: The linking command that fails is as follows.**

```
/c/Android/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-
x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libFinal.so -shared 
--sysroot=c:/Android/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm d:/Code/project
/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/Final/Final.o d:/Code/project/jni/../libs/prebuilt/
armeabi-v7a/libboost_system.a d:/Code/project/jni/../libs/prebuilt/armeabi-
v7a/libboost_date_time.a d:/Code/project/jni/../libs/prebuilt/armeabi-
v7a/libboost_filesystem.a -lgcc d:/Code/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/
lib1noproblem.so d:/Code/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/lib2noproblem.so d:/Code/
project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libproblem.so d:/Code/project/obj/local/armeabi-
v7a/libgnustl_shared.so -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Lc:/Android/
android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -lm -llog c:/Android/
android-ndk-r10b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/libsupc++.a 
-lc -lm -o d:/Code/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libFinal.so
```

Comment: Let us check if the function name is mangled correctly. Build shared libDummyProblem.so on Windows, which defines a dummy `Problem::Client::Client(std::shared_ptr<Problem::Data> const&)`, and compare its **nm** to that of the true lib produced on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could show the final link command and the full error message that it generates. Order of libraries is important when linking ELF libraries, and the undefined reference could come from that.

use 'ndk-build V=1' to dump the build commands.

Comment: Added it. Still haven't resolved the issue. I have resorted to building all my code with ajb-tools instead of ndk-build, for now.

Comment: Thanks, assuming the missing function is in libproblem.so and SomeCode.cpp in one of the libraries that appear before it on the link command, it seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you tell us about the visibility of the C++ function in libproblem.so that the linker doesn't seem to find ? What is the exact (mangled) name, and is it publicly visible ? i.e. what is the exact output of the "nm" command for this specific symbol ?